# Where Column Y Is Empty Fill In The Value From Column X

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new at this so thank you for your help and your patience.

Example: I have a shared spreadsheet with a protected range 'Y:Y' where colleagues update line items. One line item we want to flag when they change it is in column 'X:X'.

My desire is to set up a trigger that runs every 24 hours and it copies the values in column 'X:X' and pastes them into empty or blank values in column 'Y:Y'.

Then a simple DAX formula would compare X to Y. This would simplify a script I'm currently using that runs every time there's an edit.

```
function OnEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "PTL" ) { //checks that we're on PTL or not
if( s.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 7 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column G
var modify = s.getActiveCell().offset(0, 7);
modify.setValue(new Date());
var baseline = s.getActiveCell().offset(0, 6);
if( baseline.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
baseline.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function OnEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "PTL" && e.range.columnStart == 7) {
    e.range.offset(0,7).setValue(new Date());
    if (e.range.offset(0, 6).getValue() == '') 
      e.range.offset(0,6).setValue(new Date());
  }
}

function notsurewhatyouwant() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('PTL');
  const xy = sh.getRange(1, 24, sh.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  xy.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[1] == null) {
      sh.getRange(i+1,25).setValue(r[0]);
    }
  });
}

function createTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "notsurewhatyouwant").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('notsurewhatyouwant').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Perhaps you can make the example clearer by posting in your question. But yes providing examples of input and desired out would be helpful.